# How to make dynamically created elements draggable with gridstack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridstack

In my project I'm using this drag and drop library called [gridstack](https://gridstackjs.com/). You can see their documentation on github [here](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/tree/master/doc). When you hardcode elements inside the dom and initialize the gridstack, those elements are draggable. But when the elements are created dynamically with a forloop, they are not draggable even if they have the proper draggable classes. How can I make this work?

```js
//initialize grid stack
var grid = GridStack.init({
minRow: 5, // don't collapse when empty
cellHeight: 70,
acceptWidgets: true,// acceptWidgets - accept widgets dragged from other grids or from outside (default: false).
dragIn: '.newWidget',  // class that can be dragged from outside
dragInOptions: { revert: 'invalid', scroll: false, appendTo: 'body', helper:'clone' }, // clone or can be your function
removable: '#trash', // drag-out delete class
});

//gridstack on change
grid.on('added removed change', function(e, items) {
let str = '';
items.forEach(function(item) { str += ' (x,y)=' + item.x + ',' + item.y; });
console.log(e.type + ' ' + items.length + ' items:' + str );
});

//dynamic elemenets
const arr = ["Bruh cant drag me!", "Nope me neither", "Me too mouhahaha"];

//loop
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
var div = document.createElement('div');

var el = "<div class='newWidget grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide'> <div class='grid-stack-item-content' style='padding: 5px;'> "+arr[i]+"</div></div>";

div.innerHTML = el;
$('.dynamic').append(div);

}
```

```css
.grid-stack-item-removing {
opacity: 0.8;
filter: blur(5px);
}
#trash {
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
padding: 5px; 
text-align: center;
}

.grid-stack-item{
background: whitesmoke;
width: 50%;
border: 1px dashed grey;

}

.grid-stack {
background : #F0FFC0;
}
```

```html
<!-- jquery --> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- gridstack--> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gridstackjs.com/node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-extra.min.css"/>
<script src="https://gridstackjs.com/node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-h5.js"></script>

<!-- body--> 
<body>

<div id="trash"><span>drop here to remove</span> </div>

<br>

<div class="dynamic"></div>

<div class="newWidget grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide">
<div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="padding: 5px;">
<div>
</div>
<div>
<span>I'm original domster! Drag and drop me!</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="grid-stack"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was raised [here](https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/issues/1637). The grid does not automatically track external changes so the grid needs to be re-initialize for the `dragIn` option to notice the new dynamic widgets

```
GridStack.setupDragIn()
```

**Full code**

```js
//initialize grid stack
var grid = GridStack.init({
minRow: 5, // don't collapse when empty
cellHeight: 70,
acceptWidgets: true,// acceptWidgets - accept widgets dragged from other grids or from outside (default: false).
dragIn: '.newWidget',  // class that can be dragged from outside
dragInOptions: { revert: 'invalid', scroll: false, appendTo: 'body', helper:'clone' }, // clone or can be your function
removable: '#trash', // drag-out delete class
});

//gridstack on change
grid.on('added removed change', function(e, items) {
let str = '';
items.forEach(function(item) { str += ' (x,y)=' + item.x + ',' + item.y; });
console.log(e.type + ' ' + items.length + ' items:' + str );
});

//dynamic elemenets
const arr = ["Bruh cant drag me!", "Nope me neither", "Me too mouhahaha"];

//loop
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
var div = document.createElement('div');

var el = "<div class='newWidget grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide'> <div class='grid-stack-item-content' style='padding: 5px;'> "+arr[i]+"</div></div>";

div.innerHTML = el;
$('.dynamic').append(div);

}
GridStack.setupDragIn(

'.newWidget', 

);
```

```css
.grid-stack-item-removing {
opacity: 0.8;
filter: blur(5px);
}
#trash {
background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
padding: 5px; 
text-align: center;
}

.grid-stack-item{
background: whitesmoke;
width: 50%;
border: 1px dashed grey;

}

.grid-stack {
background : #F0FFC0;
}
```

```html
<!-- jquery --> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- gridstack--> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gridstackjs.com/node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-extra.min.css"/>
<script src="https://gridstackjs.com/node_modules/gridstack/dist/gridstack-h5.js"></script>

<!-- body--> 
<body>

<div id="trash"><span>drop here to remove</span> </div>

<br>

<div class="dynamic"></div>

<div class="newWidget grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide">
<div class="grid-stack-item-content" style="padding: 5px;">
<div>
</div>
<div>
<span>I'm original domster! Drag and drop me!</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="grid-stack"></div>

</body>
```